# Поиск текста в строке python

Tags: python

Стоит задача пометить строки **"!!!"** знаками, в которых содержится слово. Например:

Список:

```
  1.Яблоко
  2.Груша
  3.Апельсин
  4.Арбуз
```

Ввод с консоли для поиска -

```
text = input("Введите слово: Арбуз")
```

Итог:

```
  1.Яблоко
  2.Груша
  3.Апельсин
  4.Арбуз  !!!!!
```

Вопрос: Можно ли сделать так, чтобы мы могли писать несколько слов, для поиска? К примеру:

```
text = input("Введите слово: Арбуз,Яблоко")
```

и обязательно!!! Выход был таким:

Итог:

```
  1.Яблоко !!!!!
  2.Груша
  3.Апельсин
  4.Арбуз  !!!!!
```

То есть, одновременно, в одной строке искало совпадение сразу двух заданных слов? Без дополнительных выводов дубликатов строк и т.д

Пытался сделать так, но получается что прогоняет массив 2 раза для разных слов.

```
def GetText():
    contains = input("Введите слово: ")
    contains1 = contains.split(",")
    for fruts in contains1:
        CheckLines(fruts)
                    

def CheckLines(textToRes):
    with open("fruts.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file2:
        linesFile2 = file2.readlines()
        for lines in linesFile2:
          if textToRes in lines:
              print("!!! " +lines)
              
          print(lines)
```

Comment: 1. Можно, 2. Какие у вас были попытки решения?

Comment: @АлексейР Пробовал через "Если "искомый текст" содержится в строке, то выводим !!! + строка. Иначе вывовдим просто строку. Получилось, но с дубликатами. Либо 1 раз прогоняет массив с пометкой искомого текста, и тут же появляется второй массив со вторым текстом.

Comment: Код попытки приведите в вопросе, пожалуйста

Comment: @АлексейР Сделано!

Comment: А по-другому и никак - в любом случае количество итераций будет равно количество строк * количество слов.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В начале создаем список введенных слов в нижнем регистре, очищенных от пробелов по краям.
Потом в цикле перебираем строки файла. Во вложенном цикле перебираем введенные слова, определяя их наличие в очередной строке, переведенной также в нижний регистр (для регистронезависимого сравнения; можно вместо .lower() использовать .casefold()). Если находим, выводим текст и вск. знаки и прерываем цикл. Если не находим (else: у цикла for) то выводим только текст. Метод .rstrip() применяем, чтобы удалить ненужные нам переводы строки из файла.

```
words = [s.strip().lower() for s in input("Введите слова через запятую: ").split(',')]

with open(r"c:\test\fruts.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file2:
    for line in file2.readlines():
        linelower = line.lower()
        for word in words:
            if word in linelower:
                print(f'{line.rstrip()} !!!!')
                break
        else:
            print(f'{line.rstrip()}')
```

```
Введите слова через запятую: яблоко, груша
1.Яблоко !!!!
2.Груша !!!!
3.Апельсин
4.Арбуз
```

Вариант покороче, но менее понятный:

```
words = [s.strip().lower() for s in input("Введите слова через запятую: ").split(',')]

with open(r"c:\test\fruts.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file2:
    for line in file2.readlines():
        linelower = line.lower()
        print(f'{line.rstrip()}{" !!!!" if any(word in linelower for word in words) else ""}')
```